# How to write float values in HEX representation in C?

Tags: c

In C we support octal, binary, hex, and decimal notation.

```
int a = 16;
```

Can be also written in HEX format

```
int a = 0x10 // equivalent with 16
```

What about floats?

```
float a = 5; // using IEEE 754 0x40a00000 is the equivalence
float a == 0x40a00000 // not equivalent to 5
printf("%f",a) // will output 1084227584.000000
```

Why is that? On machine level I can find the HEX representation 40a00000 stored in the memory.

Comment: The hex representation of `5.0` is `0x5p0`.

Comment: 0x40a00000 is an integer constant. You are trying to assign integer constant to float. So in that situation, integer is converted.

Comment: I think the C standard only specifies the precision and range of `float`, not how it is encoded. So it's best to avoid trying to hard code it at bit level.

Comment: Most systems use the IEEE 754 format, but that's not guaranteed, so a hex representation could be compiled to something very wrong. If you need to, write a test program with a union of float and unsigned, set the float value you want, then print the hex representation. You can use the answer below to assign a hex value to a float also with a union.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a hexadecimal floating constant, e.g., `float a = 0x10p0; // 16.0 decimal value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the bytes of a `float` object  by using a union. The encoding is implementation-defined. Given that `float` and `unsigned` are the same size in the C implementation being used, this code will set `a` to the `float` whose value is encoded by 40A00000<sub>16</sub>:

```
float a = (union { unsigned u; float f; }) { 0x40a00000 } .f;
```

Comment: The value of a depends on `sizeof(unsigned)` and endianess

Comment: @gulpr: The answer states as a condition of the result that it is given that `float` and `unsigned` are the same size, and the answer states that the encoding is implementation-defined, which includes endianness.

Answer (score 5):

[Hexadecimal floating-point constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant) can be written like this:

```c
float a = 0x5p0f;    // 5.0f
float a = 0x1.4p2f;  // also 5.0f
```

From cppreference:

> If the significand begins with the character sequence `0x` or `0X`, the floating constant is a hexadecimal floating constant. Otherwise, it is a decimal floating constant.
>
> For a hexadecimal floating constant, the significand is interpreted as a hexadecimal rational number, and the digit-sequence of the exponent is interpreted as the integer power of 2 to which the significand has to be scaled.

---

<sup>I'm personally not used to expressing floating values like this and find it hard to construct them, but ...</sup>
Here are a few equivalent versions of approximations of π too:

```c
float pi1 = 0x1.921fb6p1f;             // hex
float pi2 = 0x3.243f6bp0f;             // hex
float pi3 = 3.1415927410125732421875f; // dec

assert(pi1 == pi2 && pi1 == pi3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memcpy` or use union.

```
float tiFloat(unsigned u)
{
    float f;
    memcpy(&f, (uint8_t[]){u, u >> 8, u >> 16, u >> 24}, sizeof(f));
    return f;
}
```

```
float tiFloatu(unsigned u)
{
    union
    {
        float x;
        uint8_t bytes[4];
    }x = {.bytes[0] = u, .bytes[1] = u >> 8, .bytes[2] = u >> 16, .bytes[3] = u >> 24};
    return x.x;
}
```

Comment: This makes the returned value depend on endianness, since it always puts the bytes into the `float` in little-endian order even if it is big-endian.